# Devise and current_user issue when using namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, namespaces, devise

On core website I use standard Devise configuration for user authentication. In routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
```

Now, I have a namespace, lets call it "frame", being used for display some views via some controllers in small window (or iframe) on remote page.
I need to authenticate user inside the frame, therefore I nested devise_for declaration:

```
namespace :frame do
  devise_for :users
  resources :albums, :only => :show do
    resources :photos, :only => [:new, :create, :show]
  end
end
```

To make the whole thing work I needed to create proper controller:

```
class Frame::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
  layout "frame"
end
```

And now I use the following path to display form:

```
new_frame_user_session_path
```

HOWEVER. When I logged in via frame, *current_user* is nil, and I have *current_frame_user* instead. It's bad, because the user logged in via core website (*current_user*) should be available via frame and reverse (in one browser).

Is there a little tweak to achive it or I should change the whole approach? Thank You for help.

Comment: My suspicion is that Rails will treat the iframe and the surrounding page as if they were two different browsers, so you won't be able to access the page's `current_user` from the frame's and vice versa. Only a hunch though.

Comment: Actually iframe is not relevant for me in this task (I use a window opened via javascript). current_user is accessible in that window when I logged in on the core site.

Comment: Why add the namespace in the first place? You can add a path option to the devise_for call if you only want to have a distinct URL... You can keep your controllers in a separate namespace by adding the controllers option to devise_for.

Comment: I need to have totally separated layout for regular sign-in and _framed_ sign-in and putting all stuff (including session) into namespace seems to be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was for me to change the log-in form in *views/frame/sessions/new.html.haml*.

Instead of:

```
= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name) do |f|
```

I needed to overwrite resource name:

```
= simple_form_for resource, :as => :user, :url => session_path(:user) do |f|
```

Now I am able to log-in within the frame and the user's session is coherent between the frame and the rest of the site.

Comment: I don't see the link between the log-in system and the current_user definition itself, are you sure you only did this ?